# Swagger not loading classes model classes on Websphere 8.5

Tags: scala, websphere, swagger, websphere-8

When I run swagger on my WAS instance, its not generating the JSON models for me.  In my logs I get this:

```
(com.wordnik.swagger.core.SwaggerContext) - Class com.foo.bar.model.TestRequest not found in classLoader
```

the UI i get is this:
[image]

This is my service code:

```
@Path("/testServiceUnit")
@Api(
        value = "/testServiceUnit",
        description = "Swagger Unit Test Service")
public class TestServiceUnit {
    /**
     * Simple Post test
     * 
     * @param tReq
     *            Request sent via post
     * @return stub response
     */
    @POST
    @Path("/tstPost")
    @ApiOperation(
            value = "Check Reference",
            notes = "code to do check cross reference for the object starts",
            response = TestResponse.class)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response checkReference(TestRequest tReq) {

        TestResponse tresp = new TestResponse();
        tresp.setTestResponder("Hello");
        return Response.status(200).entity(tresp).build();
    }
}
```

I have narrowed the problem down to this block of code within swagger:

```
package com.wordnik.swagger.core

import collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import org.slf4j.{ LoggerFactory, Logger }

object SwaggerContext {
  private val LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger("com.wordnik.swagger.core.SwaggerContext")

  var suffixResponseFormat = true

  private val classLoaders = ListBuffer.empty[ClassLoader]
  registerClassLoader(this.getClass.getClassLoader)

  def registerClassLoader(cl: ClassLoader) = this.classLoaders += cl

  def loadClass(name: String) = {
    var cls: Class[_] = null
    val itr = classLoaders.reverse.iterator
    while (cls == null && itr.hasNext) {
      try {
        cls = Class.forName(name.trim, true, itr.next)
      } catch {
        case e: ClassNotFoundException => {
          LOGGER.debug("Class %s not found in classLoader".format(name))
        }
      }
    }
    if (cls == null)
      throw new ClassNotFoundException("class " + name + " not found")
    cls
  }
}
```

Now I have switched WAS to load in both module mode, where each module in an ear has its own class loader, and application mode, where it uses one classloader for the entire EAR file.  neither work, same result.  I have also tried the scala 2.11 version, same result.  I haven't tried swagger 1.5 as it looks like it changed a LOT of code and im not in the mood to rebuild everything here.  My wAS is set to parentfirst classloading, parentlast causes the entire app to fail to load.  Im at my whits end here, I don't know what else to try.  The only thing I can think of is the IBM JVM they built into Websphere does something screwy (imagine that) but I can't for the life of me figure out why this doesn't work.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The line you included is a warning line... i.e. that the first classloader tried fails to load. Does the ClassNotFoundException also get thrown? If so, is there a log? What I mean is the output line in the log file is not a fatal error, if there are more classloaders it will keep trying. It only throws exception if cls == null hence question. BTW, don't know this code myself, just asking some exploratory questions.

Comment: It may also help saying which version of swagger-core you actually use. The scala version is completely meaningless. And by the way, upgrading to swagger-core 1.5 is not as much work as you make it seem, but I cannot guarantee it'll solve the classloading issue. There's no magic there.

Comment: we are running the latest 1.3.  No exception is thrown, but the side effect of the warning is that it doesn't translate the pojo into the expected json request and response as shown in the screen shot.  since i don't get anything else in the log other than the warning line, im assuming that the calling method is trapping the classnotfound exception and replacing the class with the fully qualified name instead of the json that it should be.  but thats a guess right now.

Comment: and i know this class doesn't seem to exist in the 1.5 branch of the code.  Since im dealing with an enterprise, trying to get the approval to use a milestone 2 class is a "thing", its really not an option for me.  Im fairly certain its something funky with IBM's jvm and/or WAS itself, i just ran out of ideas as to what it could be.